# Dependency Error with Crashlytics and ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm using Crashlytics on my project and it works fine. Except when I set the flag minifyEnabled to true and I get following error:

> Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':app:crashlyticsStoreDeobsProdRelease'.
>   > Task with path 'dexProdRelease' not found in project ':app'.

I'm using last version of Gradle Plugin and also following [Carshlytics instructions](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html) to use it with ProGuard.

I'm not using DexGuard.

Any idea what does this error mean and how to fix it ?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share which version of classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle' you're using?

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' but If I use 2.2.3 I get the same result. 

I upload full gradle files at [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertoallende/ac38c10b4749f0fae4f44098c4596713).

Note that if I change minifyEnabled to false. I don't get the error and It works.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using 1.22.2 of the Fabric Gradle plugin?